# How to show suggestion list with java.util.scanner

Tags: java

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to do a simple autocomplete system.

I have a list with 40 places names.

My objective is to show at the user all names which start with same 3 first letters than he typed on the keyboard.

Currently, to do that, I use `java.util.Scanner`.

```
private String getEntry() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    return sc.nextLine();
}
```

So, I need an "event" or a "listener" to detect when he has entered 3 letters to find and show him all places which corresponding even if the entry isn't complete.

Or display nothing if no place name begins with the 3 characters entered.

Moreover, if he types 4 letters, 5 letters, etc the autocomplete system must works too and find all names which start with the same 4 or 5 first letters.

It is possible to do that?

(I hope my explanations are clear).

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to google magic structure: **Suffix Tree**. It will solve effective your problem.

PS if you have only 40 names - then do use full scan. It is simple and quick for this small names amount.